# Failure with equinox.p2 rundirector

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install my eclipse application with equinox.run director. I am getting the below error

> Missing requirement: Sanctuary License Agent Plug-in
>   1.1.0.201603302103 (com.myproduct 1.1.0.201603302103) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I have checked this jar and its available at the location during the build of the product. What am I missing here

Comment: `org.eclipse.update.core` is part of the old Eclipse update system that was replaced with p2 a long time ago.

Comment: yes.. But I checked the documentation, which said that is we still wanna use this we can copy it from older eclipse version and it will not have any compatibility issue. For now my runner is getting blocked at this step.

Comment: I am even fine to remove this jar completely and replace the code with new equinox.p2 but I am unable to find a proper documentation of equinox.p2 APIs for such changes.